# Is there a way to access Iron Router parameter from template in Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

I have a route that has a parameter in it and I need to access it from many different templates. Below is one example of the route, there are several routes  that are very similar just after the _occasionnId parameter it changes:

For example:

Route 1: /occasions/:_occasionId/cards/

Router 2: /occasions/:_occasionId/tables/

Here is my full code for each route, the only thing that really changes is the route path and the template.

```
Router.route('/occasions/:_occasionId/cards/', {
template: 'cards',
data: function(){
//var currentoccasion = this.params._occasionId;
//console.log(currentoccasion);
},subscriptions : function(){
Meteor.subscribe('cards');
Meteor.subscribe('tables');
}
});
```

I need to get the _occasionId parameter into a template that has navigation which goes in on all of these pages. My goal is that from Route 1, you can go to Router 2. But I can't figure out how to add the correct URL in the template.

My template is:

```
<template name="occasionnav">
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="/occasions/:_occasionId/cards/">cards</a></li>
      <li><a href="/occasions/:_occasionnId/tables/">tables</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</template>
```

In the 'occasionnav' template by ":_occasionId" I need that to be the same parameter as the page currently being viewed be stuck into here.

If anyone has any insight or advice on the best way to approach this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use `{{pathFor}}` if you want to render an internal route in your Meteor application.

You just need to set the proper context and name your routes, for example:

```
<template name="occasionnav">
   <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
         <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            {{#with occasion}}
              <li><a href="{{pathFor route='occasions.cards'}}">cards</a></li>
              <li><a href="{{pathFor route='occasions.tables'}}">tables</a></li>
            {{/with}}
         </ul>
      </div>
   </nav>
</template>
```

---

```
Router.route('/occasions/:_id/cards/', {
    template: 'cards',
    name: 'occasions.cards',
    data: function() {
        return Cards.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    },
    subscriptions: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('cards', this.params._id);
    }
});
Router.route('/occasions/:_id/tables/', {
    template: 'tables',
    name: 'occasions.tables',
    data: function() {
        return Tables.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    },
    subscriptions: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('tables', this.params._id);
    }
});
```

However, you can also get the router parameters in your template via `Router.current().params`.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the _occasionId as a template helper and render it in jade like:

```
<li><a href="/occasions/{{_occasionId}}/cards/">cards</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried passing it as a template helper, it shows up only the first time I load the page. When the page is refreshed it goes away. I did it by session.set and 
'Handlebars.registerHelper('currentOccassion', function() {
  return Session.get("currentOccassion");
});'

Comment: It may be that you set the template helper with a nonreactive variable. You can put  Session.get("currentOcassion")  in that helper. It may work as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should try :

```
Router.route('/occasions/:_occasionId/cards/', function() {
  this.layout("LayoutName");
  this.render("cards", { 
     data: {
        currentoccasion = this.params._occasionId;
     }
  });
});
```

When you use Router.map, it's not exactly the same syntax:

```
Router.map(function() {
 this.route('<template name>', {
   path: 'path/:_currentoccasion',
   data: function () {
     return {
       currentoccasion: this.params._currentoccasion
     }
   }
});
```

And you can access just like that in your template :

```
Like an helper
{{ currentoccasion }}
Or on the onRendered and onCreated functions
Template.<template name>.onRendered({
  this.data.currentoccasion
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but its crashing saying that unexpected = on line 83 which is this line:
currentoccasion = this.params._occasionId;

Comment: Oh ok and can you try this one ? this.layout("LayoutName"); this.render('cards', {data: {currentoccasion = this.params._occasionId}});